# How to update collection via BlToolkit

Tags: c#, performance, entity-relationship, bltoolkit

I have collection of users identified by property **Id** and for each user I want to update his username to something like ***username+"!"***.

In bltoolkit I try it like this:

```
using(var db = new DbManager)
{
    foreach(var user in users)
    {
        db.GetTable<User>().Where(x=>x.Id == user.Id).Set(x=>x.Username, x.Username + "!").Update();
    }        
}
```

I suppose that this would make **n** queries to the database (while **n** is the size of the ***users*** collection), which is what I am trying to avoid.

Is there any other (better) solution to update whole collection like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this using to your code:

`using BLToolkit.Data.Linq`

Now you can use `Update<T>` extension method in your `DbManager`. This method allows you to do batch update by passing collection of entities as a parameter.

In your case use it like this:

```
using(var db = new DbManager)
{
    foreach(var user in users)
       user.Username = user.Username + "!";  //update each user in collection first

    db.Update<User>(users);  //just one database call for batch update
}
```